# what is the use of $.data() in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am facing some problems in the following things. Coz m a beginer in jquery. so please help regarding these. 
First I want to know:

what is the use of jquery function *`$.data()`*

How I use this in my jquery plugin
 It is good if anyone provide some clarification on this function.

Comment: `Coz`, `m a` won't help us

Comment: Very hard to find with google: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: You're kind right !? [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) The purpose of SO is not to copy/past documentations quotes

Answer (score 0):

Using `$el.data()` associates a value to the element and is stored in a object stored in memory by jQuery. This object is keyed by the element itself.

The `$.data()` method allows you access to all data attributes stored by jQuery, and you can retrieve them by providing the key element required.

Comment: still i am not able to understand its purpose.i have found one jquery calendar plugin in that $.data() function is used to store data.like $this.data(plugin_name).settings.what does it mean.?i am not able to understand its purpose.please help me.

Comment: That's using the standard `$el.data()` function *not* `$.data()`. The full documentation is available. There is really nothing I could add that isn't in there.

Answer (score 0):

From official [doc](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

> Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return
>   the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements.

Answer (score 0):

Well in the early days :-) one would add additional data to dom element by adding additional attributes.
jQuery's data created a way of adding additional data to dome element without addind additional attributes.

Answer (score 0):

$.data() is used for value of DOM attributes. like we have a dom like

```
<input id="dom1"  type ="text" data-att1="test1" />
```

Then you can get the value of attribute data-att1  using

```
$('#dom1').data('att1');
```

Answer (score 0):

In html you can put custom data value in tag.
For example :

```
<li data-numrow="12" data-author="myself">Sample tag</li>
```

`$.data("numrow")` can access easely to this data attribute on tag. it more or less a shortcut for `$.attr("data-numrow")`